# How to only load iframe block when clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, popup

I've already tried to find out how to actually do it but the codes are always different and nothing works. I always end up ruining the link or the popup itself. So, I've got this code here:

```
.popup {
    position:fixed;
    display:none;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;}

#displaybox {
    width:460px;
    margin:50px auto;
    background-color:#000000;}

.displaybox {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:800px;
    width:550px;}

.displaybox iframe {
    position:absolute;}


<link><a id="object">click link</a></link>

<script>
$(function(){
   $("link a").click(function(){
      id = $(this).attr("id");
      $(".popup:not(."+id+")").fadeOut(); $(".popup."+id).fadeIn();
   });
   $("a.close").click(function(){
      $(".popup").fadeOut();
   });
});
</script>

<div class="popup object">
    <div id="displaybox"><a class="close">x</a>
<br>
<div class="displaybox"><iframe src="{theiframeblock}" height="800" frameborder="0" width="550"></iframe></div>
</div>
```

And I want to only load the iframe-block when I click on the "click link" link. How do I have to change the script for that? Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

The snippet I provided was pretty simple, so I assume when you tested it, you either missed some of the code or placed things in the wrong order, or your site is interfering somehow.

So what I did was made the primary page (`index.html`) with everything it needs to function on it's own. I made a second page as well (`target.html`) which is the test page that resides in the iframe.

Here's the [**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/1PZoEcdyWxXAHrXhAVYl?p=preview)

---

Simplified your functions by:

- giving your popup an id `#tgt`
- removed that `<link>` element; it's not an anchor `<a>` it's basically for external stylesheets
- gave each anchor an empty `href` attribute
- placed `e.preventDefault()` in each click function to avoid the `<a>` default behavior of jumping to a location.
- replaced the iframe's `src={..}` template with the root, you can change that back, I just did that so the demo can function.

```js
$(function() {
  $("a.open").click(function(e) {
      $('#tgt').fadeIn();
      e.preventDefault();
  });
  
  $("a.close").click(function(e) {
    $("#tgt").fadeOut();
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#displaybox {
  width: 460px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background-color: #000000;
}
.displaybox {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 800px;
  width: 550px;
}
.displaybox iframe {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="" id="object" class="open" target="tgt">click link</a>



<div id="tgt" class="popup object">
  <div id="displaybox"><a href="" class="close">X</a>
    <br>
    <div class="displaybox">
      <iframe src="/" height="800" frameborder="0" width="550"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much! c: I changed the codes according to your instructions, however, the iframe page still loads simultaneously with the main page. I meant to ask if there's a way to only load the iframe block when opening the link? Is there anything else that needs to be changed in the script?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$("#object").click(function() { 
   $("iframe").attr("src", "http://www.your-url.com");     
});
```

Won't allow cross-origin requets

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by using jQuery

Try this - https://jsfiddle.net/van06539/

***HTML-***

```
<a href="#" id="openFrame">Click Link</a>
<div id="iFrameContainer">
  <iframe src="http://www.bbc.com" id="bestIframeEver" height="600" width="300" style="display:none;">

  </iframe>
</div>
```

***Javascript -***

```
var isOpened = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#openFrame").click(function() {
    if (!isOpened) {
      $("#bestIframeEver").fadeIn(1000);
    } else {
      $("#bestIframeEver").fadeOut(1000);
    }
    isOpened = !isOpened;
  });
});
```

You can toggle the open / close state of the iframe